# Homebrew: can't run ag (The Silver Searcher)

Tags: homebrew

My homebrew install of `ag` fails with:

```
$ ag
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libpcre.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/ag
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

What do I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A [Japanese blog post](http://chaika.hatenablog.com/entry/2014/06/11/170441) covers what's necessary to fix this.  `libpcre.1.dylib` is a file provided by the pcre Homebrew package.

The fix for this is to `brew uninstall pcre && brew install pcre`.  `ag` should work after this.

Comment: Had found the japanese post... but abandoned when I realized I couldn't understand a thing. Thank you for getting the answer out of it!

Answer (score 2):

You SHOULD run `brew doctor` and follow what they suggested.

Mine is `You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar due to the permission errors`.

To fix this:  run `sudo chown yourname /lib/local/lib` then run `brew link pcre`.